# Get tags for current user

Tags: users, tags

How i can get user tags list , i get list of all tags with this:

```
<?php $tags = get_tags(); ?>

<?php if (isset($tags)): ?>
    <ul>

        <?php foreach ($tags as $tag): ?>
            <li><?php echo $tag->name; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>

    </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

This return me list of all used tags on my wordpress page.

My question is: How can I get only the tags *assigned to posts* written by the currently logged user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The currently logged in user

The `\WP_User` object/instance can be retrieved via:

```
$user = get_current_user();
```

There's a shortcut API wrapper to fetch the ID:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

### `$wpdb` and the WP "DBAL"

WP basically uses `$wpdb` as DBAL/Database Abstraction Layer. It got plenty of public methods and some higher level wrappers for convenient access. One is `get_posts_by_author_sql()`:

```
var_dump( get_posts_by_author_sql( 'post', true, get_current_user_id() ) );

# Result:
string 'WHERE post_author = 1 AND post_type = 'post' AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'private')' (length=101)
```

*If you just want public posts, use the 4th argument and set it to `true`.*

The next step would be to build a complete query:

```
$sql = "select {$wpdb->posts}.id from {$wpdb->posts} ".get_posts_by_author_sql( 'post', true, get_current_user_id() );
```

Now you can bolt this onto a `$wpdb` query. Don't forget to only conditionally turn on debug mode. Also don't add debug to a live site as statically cached sites may print your DB credentials to the public for quite some time.

```
/** @var \wpdb $wpdb */
global $wpdb;
if (
    defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) and WP_DEBUG
    and defined( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY' ) and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY
)
    $wpdb->show_errors();

$posts = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
// Filter out only the post IDs and build an array from the result:
$posts = wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'id' );
```

Now we only need to fetch the tags. We then build a new array and collect the tags - ordered by post IDs. This might end up having duplicate tags. If you don't want that, you will have to implement a different sorting and fetching mechanism. It's not that hard, as you can easily pluck terms based on the `object_id` property which in fact just is the post ID.

```
$tags = [];
foreach ( $posts as $post_id )
    $tags[ $post_id ] = get_the_tags( $post_id );

var_dump( $tags );
```

*Keep in mind that prior to PHP v5.4 you will need `array()` instead of the short array syntax `[]`.*

The result will look like the following and you get full term *objects* in return.

```
array (size=13)
  167 => 
    array (size=16)
      50 => 
        object(stdClass)[50]
          public 'term_id' => int 50
          public 'name' => string '8BIT' (length=4)
          public 'slug' => string '8bit' (length=4)
          public 'term_group' => int 0
          public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 50
          public 'taxonomy' => string 'post_tag' (length=8)
          public 'description' => string 'Tags posts about 8BIT.' (length=22)
          public 'parent' => int 0
          public 'count' => int 1
          public 'object_id' => int 167
          public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
      51 => 
        object(stdClass)[10]
          public 'term_id' => int 51
          public 'name' => string 'Articles' (length=8)
          public 'slug' => string 'articles' (length=8)
          public 'term_group' => int 0
          ...
```

### Posts amount

To fetch the amount of posts the currently logged in user has written, use:

```
$count = count_user_posts( get_current_user_id() );
// Will return an integer
```

Comment: @user3501587 You are welcome :)

Comment: How i can remove repeatable tags from list ?
Thanks!

Comment: That highly depends on what you want to do. What if a repeated tag is needed in list B, but not in A and vice versa? Anyway, you need to modify the `foreach` loop and just build a different array.

Comment: okey, thanks.
and next question, how i can get "future" posts?
what add to sql?

Comment: Please, search the site or ask a new question for that. There is no such thing as 1:1 support in comments. Thanks.